# what does the "wv" means on an user-agent string

Tags: android, google-chrome, user-agent

I'm searching how to detect if the user accessed the website via a captive portal (like when you connect to a WiFi LAN and it ask to login), so I'm trying to decipher the user-agent strings, my own phone return this when accessing into the captive portal:

```
mozilla/5.0 (linux; android 7.1.2; vibe k5 plus build/njh47b; wv) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) version/4.0 chrome/61.0.3163.98 mobile safari/537.36
```

and this while accessing the page via normal chrome:

```
mozilla/5.0 (linux; android 7.1.2; vibe k5 plus build/njh47b) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/61.0.3163.98 mobile safari/537.36
```

the biggest difference I saw at the `vw` string, but I couldn't find anything about this string in user-agents explanations, any one got ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent:

> In the newer versions of WebView, you can differentiate the WebView by
>   looking for the wv field